# Error in connecting OLEDB and ODBC databases in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

While trying to connect the OLEDB databases with .NET Framework, I get a syntax error in the `INSERT INTO` statement., when running in a 64-bit Windows version.

The same code is running perfectly fine in Windows 32-bit.

I read on the Windows site that Windows does not provide support for 64-bit models.

Is there a work around to this problem?

```
string vSrc = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\abhi.mdb";
OleDbConnection vconn = new OleDbConnection(vSrc);
vconn.Open();

string vSname = TextBox1.Text;
string vQuery = "insert into Table(Sname)values('"+vSname+"') ";

OleDbCommand vcomm = new OleDbCommand(vQuery, vconn);
vcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
Label1.Text = "record save successfully";
vconn.Close();
```

Comment: What windows does not support

Comment: Please show the code ..it would be better for the rest of us to lend a more productive answer. Thanks

Comment: Abhishek: I fixed the presentation of your code so that it's easier to read. You've just changed it back to more difficult to read. Why?

Comment: It's a fact! JET.OLEDB.4.0 is not available in apps compiled for 64bit mode.

Comment: @AmritpalSingh You need to provide the EXACT exception, pretty sure it is not really the insert but a missing 64bit provider/driver

Comment: @ntziolis yes thats my point is, Also as he states that it works in 32 bit and not now. so i think insert should not be an issue

Answer (score 2):

Apparently my hunch was correct. `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider is not 64-bit compatible:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/14041b74-6ca6-49be-af90-d8ff3f962724

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal If the website is running on a x64 IIS in a x64 Application Pool it will cause the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you have error regarding 64 bit access driver you should look at

[Windows 7 64 bit odbc drivers for Ms Access Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721702/windows-7-64-bit-odbc-drivers-for-ms-access-missing)